On C*-rigidity problem for torsion-free groups
I'd like to address the $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-rigidity problem for
torsion-free groups (see
this paper),
which asks for non-isomorphic torsion-free groups with isomorphic
(reduced) group $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra.
A strategy is to find a group construction (HNN extension, etc.)
on some base group which is non-trivial
at the level of groups but become trivial at the level of operator algebras.
The simplest situation we look for is:

(1) $x$ and $y$ in a torsion-free group $\Gamma$, which are not conjugate in $\Gamma$ but are conjugate in $\mathrm{C}^\ast_{\mathrm{r}}\Gamma$.

Then the HNN-extension groups
$$\Gamma_1:=\langle \Gamma, s : sxs^{-1} = y \rangle
\mbox{ and }
\Gamma_2:=\langle \Gamma, t : txt^{-1} = x \rangle$$
are not "obviously-isomorphic", but have isomorphic reduced group $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra.
Finding (1) is same as finding

(2) a torsion-free group $\Gamma$, an automorphism $\sigma$ (which may have finite order), and $z\in\Gamma$, where the "cocycle" $z$ does not untwists in $\Gamma$ (i.e., $z = x\sigma(x^{-1})$ for no $x\in\Gamma$), but untwists in $\mathrm{C}^\ast_{\mathrm{r}}\Gamma$.

Remark: It is rather easy to find examples in the von Neumann algebra setting:
$x,y\in\Gamma$ and $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}\Gamma$ such that
$\ker\lambda(\zeta)=0$ on $\ell_2\Gamma$ (automatic if Atiyah Conjecture is true) and
$x\zeta = \zeta y$, giving rise to non-isomorphic groups with isomorphic group von Neumann algebra.

Proof of the claim that $x \zeta = \zeta y$ with
$\zeta\in(\mathrm{C}^\ast_r\Gamma)^{-1}$
implies
$\mathrm{C}^\ast_r\Gamma_1\cong
\mathrm{C}^\ast_r\Gamma_2$.
By polar decomposition, we may assume that $\zeta$ is unitary.
We claim that the homomorphism $\theta$ from $\Gamma_2$
into $\mathrm{C}^\ast_r\Gamma_1$, defined by $\theta|_\Gamma=\mathrm{id}_\Gamma$ and $\theta(t)=\zeta s$, extends to a $\ast$-isomorphism between the reduced group $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebras. We only show that $\theta$ is continuous. For this, it suffices to check that $\theta$ preserves the canonical trace,
i.e., $\mathrm{tr}(\theta(a))=0$ for all $a\neq1$.
Let $a\in \Gamma_2\setminus\Gamma$ be given and
expand it as $a=a_0t^{k_1}a_1t^{k_2}\cdots t^{k_n}a_n$, where
$n\geq1$, $k_i\neq0$, and $a_i\in\Gamma$
with $a_i\notin \langle x\rangle$ for $0<i<n$.
Since $\Gamma_1$ is an HNN extension and Britton's lemma applies,
one only has to check there is no $sx^ks^{-1}$ nor $s^{-1}y^ls$
in the sub-word of the terms of
$$\theta(a) = a_0 (\zeta s)^{k_1} a_1 (\zeta s)^{k_2} \cdots (\zeta s)^{k_n}a_n$$
when $\zeta$ and $\zeta^{-1}$ in $\mathrm{vN}(\Gamma)$ are expanded as Fourier series.
The word $sx^ks^{-1}$ does not occur because
$a_i \notin \langle x\rangle$.
The word $s^{-1}y^ls$ possibly occurs only in
the Fourier expansion of $s^{-1}\zeta^{-1} a_i \zeta s$.
However, $y^l\in\mathop{\mathrm{supp}} \zeta^{-1} a_i \zeta$ (that is, $\mathrm{tr}( y^{-l} \zeta^{-1} a_i \zeta)\neq0$)
if and only if
$a_i\in\mathop{\mathrm{supp}}  \zeta y^l \zeta^{-1} =\{ x^l \}$, which is impossible.

I am being slow: what are examples of torsion-free $\Gamma$ such that there are non-conjugate elements $x,y$ and $\zeta\in {\mathbb C}\Gamma$ satisfying $x\zeta=\zeta y$?

If such $\zeta$ can be chosen self-adjoint, then it seems you could build a unitary $u\in M_2({\rm C}^\ast_r(\Gamma))$ such that ${\rm diag}_2(x) u = u {\rm diag}_2(y)$; would that get us closer to a non-isomorphic pair of groups with isomorphic reduced group Cstar algebra?

(1) The simplest example is $\langle a,u : uau^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle$. One has $(1+a) u^{-1}=(u^{-1}a^{-1}) (1+a)$. Hence although $u$ and $au$ are not conjugate in the group (nor in the C*-algebra because of $K_1$), they are conjugate in the group von Neumann algebra. (2) It does not seem to give us group algebra of torsion-free groups. The group C*-algebra of a torsion-free group shall not have nontrivial projections if Kadison's conjecture is true.

Thanks Taka. Regarding the last part, my hope was that if one had $M_2({\rm C}^\ast_r(\Lambda_1)) \cong M_2({\rm C}^\ast_r(\Lambda_2))$ then one might be able to deduce ${\rm C}^\ast_r(\Lambda_1)\cong {\rm C}^\ast_r(\Lambda_2)$, but I did not have any method in mind for achieving this ...

BTW, there's a further example.
$\Gamma=\langle a,b,c,u : u^{-1}au=a^{-1},  u^{-1}bu=b^{-1},  u^{-1}cu=a^{-1}cb^{-1}\rangle$. $\mathrm{Ad}_u$ is an order 2 automorphism on the free subgroup $\langle a,b,c \rangle$. The element $a$ is a cocycle for this automorphism.
$\zeta au = u\zeta$ for $\zeta=1+a^{-1}$ and $\zeta=(1+b)c^{-1}$
which are "collectively injective".
(There's a systematic way of producing more such examples, but
I don't want people to follow my failed path.)

Taka, in your “proof of claim”, did you mean to write $\text{vN}(\Gamma_1) \cong \text{vN}(\Gamma_2)$ instead of the group $C^\ast$-algebras being isomorphic?

@David Gao: The proof is for continuity of $\theta$ on $\mathrm{vN}(\Gamma_2)$. If $\zeta\in\mathrm{C}^\ast_{\mathrm{r}}(\Gamma)$ (resp. $\mathrm{vN}(\Gamma)$), then $\theta$ is an isomorphism between the reduced group $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebras (resp. the group vN algebras).

I have revised the proof.

@NarutakaOZAWA Ah, no, I understand that. I just thought you were referencing the remark just before the proof. So I interpreted $\zeta \in (C_r^\ast\Gamma)^{-1}$ as meaning $\text{ker}(\zeta) = 0$, in which case the use of polar decomposition requires vNa. I now realize you wrote $(C_r^\ast\Gamma)^{-1}$ for invertible elements of $C_r^\ast\Gamma$, in which case the proof is certainly fine.
